# How can I install TypeScript declarations for scoped/namespaced packages via @types?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, types, definitelytyped

I'm using TypeScript and I want to use a scoped package (e.g. `@foo/bar`, `@babel/core`, etc.) that doesn't ship its own type declarations.

I've tried to run something like

```
npm install @types/@foo/bar
```

but it doesn't seem to be available.

Is there any way to get these `.d.ts` for these packages into the `@types` scope? Is there a way to write my own scoped packages on DefinitelyTyped if I need to?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is there any way to get these `.d.ts` for these packages into the `@types` scope?

Yes there is a way! It's just a little unintuitive.

npm doesn't permit scoped packages to contain `@` in their name, so these names are mangled to **use two underscores in place of the `@`**.

So as an example, if you want to install type declarations for the package `@foo/bar`, you'll need to run

```
npm install @types/foo__bar
```

---

> Is there a way to write my own scoped packages on DefinitelyTyped if I need to?

Yes! From the [Definitely Typed README.md](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/987a09b4979415a83491328a57cf4def5b7e1bc7#what-about-scoped-packages):

> Types for a scoped package `@foo/bar` should go in `types/foo__bar`. Note the double underscore.

Comment: Is there a way to write my own scoped packages **outside** DefinitelyTyped if I need to? -- DefinitelyTyped is just too slow to accept pull requests...

Comment: I like this answer but as a nitpick maybe it should be noted that the two underscores are not "in place of the @" - it's not `@types/__foo/bar`. The two underscores replace both the `@` and the `/`. In other words, the `@` is _removed_ and the `/` is replaced by `__`: `@scope/package` => `scope__package`.